# Looped characters in a file

Tags: batch-file, replace

I have a program that creates a file myself.txt like this

```
2020/05/04 19:11:43      10113  35.11154    6.69945   2.081 254
2020/05/04 19:12:04      10113  35.11159    6.69926   1.294 294
2020/05/04 19:12:10      10100  35.08132    6.67381   1.997 346
```

Is it possible with a batch to eliminate part of each row in order to have this result?

```
2020/05/04 19:11:43      10113  35.11154
2020/05/04 19:12:04      10113  35.11159
2020/05/04 19:12:10      10100  35.08132
```

Comment: Well, the answer is: Yes. Please read [ask]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
(   for /f "tokens=1-4" %%A in (myself.txt) do (
        echo %%A %%B      %%C  %%D
    )
) > new.txt
```

Your file has 7 tokens yet you want just the 1st 4 tokens. `for /f` loop with option `tokens=1-4` will get you the 1st 4 tokens.

Comment: This method requires to count the spaces in the input data and hard-code them in the program.

Answer (score 0):

This method preserve the same data up to a given token, including *the same existing spaces* in the line.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "delims=*" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   call :PreserveUpToToken#4 %%a
)) > output.txt
goto :EOF

:PreserveUpToToken#4
set "line=%*"
set "line=!line:%4=%4& rem!"
echo %line%
exit /B
```

Comment: This won't work if the value in the 4th column also appears within one of the earlier columns, even as a substring. Obviously not a problem with the sample data, but in the general sense, definitely a concern. Also problems if 4th column contains `=`..